# Need correct sql command to delete where CHAR_LENGTH() more than

Tags: sql, truncate, sql-delete

I need the correct SQL command to delete where CHAR_LENGTH() more than x amount I tried

```
TRUNCATE * FROM foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(foobar) > 100
```

(also tried DELETE *)

which according to [w3cshools](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/sql_where.asp) is a valid operator but it just comes back as error:

*> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(foobar) > 100' at line 1*

***Note:*** The error message actually shows  > as ASCII "& gt;" (no space or quotes) not sure if that has any relevance ...

I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(foobar) > 100
```

Just to see if that would do anything and it did what was expected and showed all with a charcount greater then 100.

As always any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) operation, not [TRUNCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html).

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(foobar) > 100;
```

TRUNCATE have this syntax:

```
TRUNCATE foo;
```

and empties the table completely. You cannot have a WHERE clause on TRUNCATE.

Comment: Sorry edited original post as you where posting, yeah I tried DELETE but get same error but when I used SELECT it did its job.

Comment: Note that DELETE does not take a column list so you need to remove the `*` (I missed that in my original post but have edited it to fit now).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `TRUNCATE TABLE` with a where clause ([Ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html).)

Use [`DELETE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) instead:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(foobar) > 100
```